# Creating an overlay on a view's content does not work with AbsoluteLayout

Tags: sapui5

My intention is to have a view with an overlay over the its content and bind the visibility of that overlay to a property of the model. As you see from the plnkr example everything works ok with the absolute layout if the height is set in "px" but does not work if height is set in "%".

Please have a look at the following plunker, file Product.view.js at line 46: http://plnkr.co/edit/1RON6ryRt32d5S461h9m?p=preview

```
var oAbsLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.AbsoluteLayout({
  width: "100%",
  height: "100px", //THIS ONLY WORKS HERE IF WE SET THE HEIGHT IN "px". DOES NOT WORK WITH %, so the content will be cutt-off
  verticalScrolling: sap.ui.core.Scrolling.Hidden,
  horizontalScrolling: sap.ui.core.Scrolling.Hidden
});
```

If I specify the height of the absolute layout in px then the Product view is rendered ok, but the content inside will be cut off in case of wrapping. (the height of the content is not fixed).

Any other ideas how to obtain the overlay over a view? You can play around with that plunker.

Many thanks!